# What to do during long-ish connection in Rome Fiumicino airport with children?

Tags: airports, children, layovers, rome, fco

I travel with three kids (ages 4, 8, 9) and have a 5 hours connection in Rome Fiumicino airport (FCO). Assuming the planes are on time, that leaves 3-4 hours to fill in or around the airport.

I would assume that there isn't enough time to get into Rome, especially not when trying it with 3 children, is that likely to be correct? However, things near the airport should work, if there is anything to visit? Or failing that something children friendly in the airport itself!

Are there any "kid-friendly" activities or places in or near the airport?

Comment: You're going to need to be clearer on what kind of activity you expect. Are you in particular interested in kids activity?

Comment: Are you looking for things to do in and around the airport, or are you willing to make a short trip to somewhere nearby if that's available?